# Send custom instructions (or fields) to Google Checkout

Tags: grails, e-commerce, google-checkout

Is there a way to add a "Notes" or "Delivery Instructions" field to a Google Checkout post? I'm using the [Custom Cart HTML API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Cart_How_To_HTML.html) and it's worked out great so far except that I want to include a section for the buyer to add notes about the delivery.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Of course after I post the question I find the answer.</sup>

Google offers tags to indicate that you want to add gift or special instructions at checkout. This [Gift Messaging API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Gift_Messaging.html) can be used to allow a Gift or other message to be included, as well as allowing you to pre-fill it with input from the customer.

```
<input type="hidden" name="shopping-cart.buyer-messages.special-instructions-1" value="" />
```